# Back file from imac

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to backup files from my imac using ubuntu live cd, but it wont allowed me to, because of the file system type, imac partition type using the HFS/HFS+ system, i've tried run as root, still it wont allow me to copy, i've also tried run the nautilus as root, also can't get it, anyone please guide me to save my file, thanks

Answer (score 0):

get these files from synaptic package manager or sudo apt-get.

**hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs libhfsp0**

```
sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs libhfsp0
```

reboot to be safe and you should be good to go.

If you want to access or use time machine backups you will also need **tmfs** ... but that is a whole different challenge.

I know this works with Debian and Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 LTS releases.

Comment: tested it- and it even works from the Live disk... and does not need a reboot. :)